How to check if an Active Job is running inline in Rails?
I'm trying to determine if a job in my Rails application is running inline (i.e., synchronously) or asynchronously. How can an ActiveJob instance know if it was executed inline with perform_now or in the background with perform_later?
I know I can check the provider_job_id attribute, but I'm looking for a more Rails-way.
Is there a built-in method or attribute that I can use to check if an Active Job is running inline?
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:
    class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
      def perform
        if # job is running inline
          # do something
        else
          # do something else
        end
      end
    end


Try this custom approach:
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  attr_accessor :running_inline

  before_enqueue do |job|
    job.running_inline = false
  end

  def perform(*args)
    if running_inline
      # Job is running inline
      puts "Running inline"
    else
      # Job is running asynchronously
      puts "Running asynchronously"
    end
  end

  def perform_now
    self.running_inline = true
    super
  end
end


I liked this approach, but couldn't get it to work. I think the attribute is lost after its enqueued.

What issue you are facing?
